# file command reports text/plain for .css file

Tags: mime-type, xdg-open

I'm trying to get xdg-open to open css files with correct editor, but can't get `file` to report correct mimetype for a file.css file. There is an entry both in /etc/mime.types and a file already exist as /usr/share/mime/text/css.xml but this always happens:

```
➜  ~  echo ". {}" > file.css
➜  ~  file --mime-type file.css
file.css: text/plain
➜  ~
```

When I trace the code, I see that it uses magic instead of /usr/share/mime/text mime db. How can I get file to report this as text/css instead of text/plain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use `file -i` or `file --mime-type` to test the functionality of the system-wide MIME database. `file` uses `magic` and its config by default, so to change the behavior of `file`, you would have to change the `magic` config.

To **check and modify the `xdg-open` behavior instead**, you should use the **XDG-Utilities**. For example, you can **check the current settings** how to handle files with `text/plain` MIME type:

```
~ $ xdg-mime query default text/plain
```

On my Mint laptop, it returns

```
gedit.desktop
```

For `text/css`, there's usually no default application set (you can check this using `xdg-mime query default text/css`). To **change this and set GEdit as default CSS editor**, you could use the following command:

```
~ $ xdg-mime default gedit.desktop text/css
```

This will insert a line in `/home/<Username>/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with `text/css=gedit.desktop`. Instead of using xdg-mime, you could modify the `mimeapps.list` directly.

Now, `xdg-mime query` returns the application i've chosen ...

```
~ $ xdg-mime query default text/css
gedit.desktop
```

... and `xdg-open /tmp/file.css` will start GEdit and load the CSS fiile.

See also this [page on `xdg-open` from the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open).

Comment: Thanks, saved the day! My error was that I thought xdg-open got info from file.